# Need grammar book recommendations for review for former advanced speaker

Tags: resource, book

Edit: I phrased the question ambiguously it seems. I appreciate all answers, but basically I'm looking for a thorough and yet relatively quick way to review German grammar. With "book" I meant grammar book, although I'm open to other media. I am sorry if I was unclear....

Some time ago I had a pretty high level of German - high C1 or low C2? -- through study and living two years in German speaking countries. Time, lack of practice, and other foreign languages have somewhat eroded that. I'm keen to recuperate my skills. So I'm looking for books and other resources to help with a "re-infusion" of German, especially grammar and vocabulary. I have a lot of grammar "burned in" -- I know what's right without remembering why, just instinctually. Which is good. But there are many holes. I found a good series of books and swallowing my pride am starting with A1, although I have some concern that if I think too much about what I'm doing I might lose the instinct.  I'll move from there to B and C levels.  But I'd also like to get a parallel track going which will move me ahead quicker, as many parts of my abilities are still high level, and I don't want to sabotage myself by getting bored.

Books in German are fine -- I live in the EU so might be easier to get -- as well as English. Any other suggestions welcome. Danke vielmals!

Comment: Der erste einfache Schritt wäre: Schreibe diese Frage auf Deutsch! Du hast sehr viel Deutsch in Deinem Gehirn vergraben, du must es nur freilegen, und das geht durch aktives Benützen. - Zweitens: lies deutsche Zeitungen; höre deutsche Radiosendungen (v.a. Deutschlandfunk); das geht ja leicht übers Internet.

Comment: PS: Note that *language in use* always comes with grammar and vocabulary.

Comment: You're searching for English book recommendations to improve your German? For German books, without further information, go for Nobel Prize winners and other famous, decorated Authors (Börsenpreis d. dt. Buchhandels, empfohlener Kanon von Marcel Reich-Ranicki). Do you prefer modern works (R.D.Brinkmann, Thomas Bernhard, Elfriede Jelinek) or older stuff (Kleist, Göthe, Heine)? Or are you more in SciFi or Crime, Romanze or Poems, ...

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because I think book recommendations are potentially helpful. [This meta post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/518/what-to-do-with-our-book-recommendation-questions) links some questions of that type that have not been closed.